# awk - collapsing files with same date + getting sum of column

Tags: awk

this is my question, - awk - collapsing files with same date + getting sum of column - but there might be a better way of wording it, aggregating...

1/
this is my output:

```
> awk -F' {2,}' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $5 =="1927" {cnt++} ENDFILE{print FILENAME, (cnt>0&&cnt?cnt:"0"); cnt=0}' /log/msg/sched/kevin_nbr_deletion/2023-01-31_*_table.log | head
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_600010_table.log,0
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_600012_table.log,0
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_600014_table.log,0
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_600016_table.log,0
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_600018_table.log,0
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_600020_table.log,0
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_600024_table.log,0
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_600026_table.log,0
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_600028_table.log,0
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_618100_table.log,0
```

2/
And from this I want to colapse all these files into one and show the sum of the times the pattern is matched.

```
> awk -F' {2,}' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $5 =="1927" {cnt++} ENDFILE{print FILENAME, (cnt>0&&cnt?cnt:"0"); cnt=0}' /log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_*_table.log | head | awk -F, '{print substr($1,35,10)}'
2023-01-31
2023-01-31
2023-01-31
2023-01-31
2023-01-31
2023-01-31
2023-01-31
2023-01-31
2023-01-31
2023-01-31
```

3

```
> awk -F' {2,}' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $5 =="1927" {cnt++} ENDFILE{print FILENAME, (cnt>0&&cnt?cnt:"0"); cnt=0}' /log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_*_table.log | head | awk -F, '{sum+=$2} END{print sum}'
0
>
```

how do I combine 2 and 3 together to get this output,

```
2023-01-31,0
```

Or better still if I change the wild card to pick up more files:
then I want output like this

```
2023-01-30,0
2023-01-31,0
2023-02-01,0
```

Or even combine 1 2 and 3 into one.

Comment: Provide input data from actual log files and it's corresponding expected output.

Comment: You've asked and received answers to multiple questions but don't appear to be learning from the responses you're getting. What do you think `-F' {2,}' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` does, for example? Hint: you were explicitly [told about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75304719/how-do-i-add-a-comma-as-my-delimiter-for-the-output-of-awk#comment132889581_75304719) in a comment under a previous question. Get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn about awk.

Comment: See the final script in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75291366/1745001) you accepted and copied the script in your question from for what to write instead of the convoluted `(cnt>0&&cnt?cnt:"0")`.

Comment: @EdMorton re `"-F' {2,}' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}"` i see your point but in this case does first `-F' {2,}'` use 2 spaces as delimiter and does `'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` this set the output delimiter? I guess how do I have a different delimiter for in put and one for output? does this work removing the redundency? `-F' {2,}' 'BEGIN{OFS=","}`

Comment: That BEGIN statement sets both FS and OFS, overwriting the FS value from `"-F' {2,}'`. You COULD set FS using `-F` and `OFS` iin the BEGIN section but the most important thing in software is consistency so either set them both up front using flags or set them both in BEGIN. In this case, though, `-F' {2,}'` is probably not desirable, depending on what your input (which is missing from your question) looks like and so you should just remove that and leave `'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}`

Answer (score 0):

To simulate OP's current `awk` output:

```
$ cat awk.out
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_600010_table.log,0
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_600012_table.log,0
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_600014_table.log,0
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_600016_table.log,0
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_600018_table.log,0
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_600020_table.log,0
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_600024_table.log,0
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_600026_table.log,0
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_600028_table.log,0
/log/msg/sched/xxyyzz/2023-01-31_06:05:00_eNB_618100_table.log,0
```

One simple fix for the current code:

```
cat awk.out | 
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
      { date=substr($1,23,10)               # OP will need to review the start position (23 vs 35 vs something else) based on actual data; otherwise this could be expanded to parse the filename based on delimiters
        datesums[date]+=$2
      }
END   { for (i in datesums)
            print i,datesums[i]
      }
'
```

This generates:

```
2023-01-31,0
```

'course, this should be pulled into the main `awk` script, and the hardcoded `substr()` could be replaced with something a bit more dynamic; one idea:

```
awk -F' {2,}' '
BEGIN       { FS=OFS="," }
$5 =="1927" { cnt++ } 
ENDFILE     { if (match($1,/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/)) {
                 date=substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH)
                 datesums[date]+=(cnt+0)
              }
              cnt=0
            }
END         { for (i in datesums)
                  print i,datesums[i]
            }
' /log/msg/sched/kevin_nbr_deletion/2023-01-31_*_table.log
```

**NOTE:** without actual input files I'm not going to try to address the dual delimiter definitions (`-F' {2,}'` vs `FS=OFS=","`)